# Where's a good C++ 2D rendering engine?

Tags: rendering, 2d

I am building a script creator for [this](http://www.skyscrapersim.com/). I'm using OGRE for the 3D bit, but to build a building I'll need something in 2D that can draw stuff depending on where you click (a bit like [this](http://beno.org.uk/metromapcreator/)). I don't care what platform it's on (as long as it's Windows).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Shopping questions are explicitly off topic.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129153/are-im-looking-for-xyz-project-plugin-library-for-language-zyx-on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

There some choices:

- Vigra
- AGG
- Olena
- [Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/)
- [Skia](https://skia.org/)

Any one is satisfied what you need. I prefer Skia. 
QT focus on UI, nothing relevance to 2D rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a simple cross-platform low-level rendering engine, you could use the Simple DirectMedia Layer (libsdl.org).

For more higher-level programming I prefer Qt. Qt is a complete Framework for many purposes. You can make custom rendering stuff with the qgraphicsview/qgraphicsscene classes.

If you are a beginner, you should use libsdl, because it is easier to learn.